# i have a string str="75,75,83,84" i want remove duplicate from this in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

string str="75,75,83,84"

I want to remove repeating values from the string, I provide one example of a string.`string str+=Id.ToString() + ",";`

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Do you know how to split a string into an array?  How to compare values?  What isn't working?

Comment: To add to what @David is saying, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would go a long way to helping us help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`string.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) to split the string into separate values, e.g.

```
var input = "75,75,83,84";
var values = input.Split(',');
```

Afterwards, you can remove duplicates from the values using [`Enumerable.Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2), e.g.:

```
var distinctValues = values.Distinct();
```

Then you can use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2) to join the string again, e.g.:

```
var output = string.Join(",", distinctValues);
```

Comment: From the snippet in the question, I guess OP could even drop the string splitting by first building a `List<int>` (or similar) _instead_, then distinct, then join.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ you can do:

```
string str = "75,75,83,84";
str = string.Join(",",str.Split(',').Distinct());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.Split()` to obtain an array of string that contain all values.
Then you could use the `string[].Distinct()` extension method from the `System.Linq` namespace to eliminate duplicates.
Finally you can glue all values together with `String.Join()` method.

```
string str="75,75,83,84";
string unique = string.Join(',', str.Split(',').Distinct());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "75,75,83,84";
        string[] strarray = str.Split(',');
        string newValue = "";
        foreach (var item in strarray)
        {
            if (!newValue.Contains(item))
            {
                newValue = (newValue == "") ? item : newValue + ", " + item;
            }
        }
```

Now you will get non-repeating values in newValue variable.

Comment: This code doesn't compile.  The `Split` method does not take a `string` as an argument.

Comment: Yes @ChrisDunaway you are right. this is my mistake actually split method take argument with single quote. **Thanks for correct me**.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
String foo = "10,10,50,22,12";
String[] fooInPieces = foo.Split(',');
foo = '';
List<string> fooNoDuplicate = new List<string>();
foreach (string piece in fooInPieces) {
    bool noDuplicate = true;
    foreach (string doublePiece in fooNoDuplicate) {
        if (doublePiece.replace(',', '') == piece.replace(',' '')
            noDuplicate = false;
    }
    if (noDuplicate){
        fooNoDuplicate.Add(piece);
        foo += piece;
    }
}
```

*String.replace(',', '')* makes sure that the last digits can't be duplicates, since they're always different (no comma at the end).

*String.split(',')* turns the digits into pieces whenever it finds a comma.
You then start adding the pieces to *fooNoDuplicate* (the length of a list doesn't need to be defined). You can then check if the same variable already exists within the list before adding.

Comment: Why not just `List<string> fooNoDuplicate = fooInPieces.Distinct().ToList();`?

Comment: Because i was not aware that it was this easy!
But don't you still have the problem of the last number not having a comma, so it will never be a duplicate of the others?